# How can I read a input file in kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, import, kibana

I have to do some operation on a vtt file in kibana. But I am unable to read it in kibana. please suggest me some ways to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Kibana is just a visualization tool that lets you search data in elasticsearch in a graphical manner. So primarily you want to index the data from your file into elasticsearch in order to see them in kibana.

You may want to take a look at [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/introduction.html) in general and especially at its [File Input Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html). With this, you can read lines of a file and apply multiple so-called filters on the events to process them. To index the events (= line of file) you would need to use the [Elasticsearch Output Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html).

As an alternative to Logstash's File Input Plugin you could install and configure [Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-overview.html) on the particular host to read the certain file. Since you need to do some processing I recommend to send the data from Filebeat to Logstash. In this scenario, you would need to use Logstash's [Beats Input Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-beats.html).

Comment: @pandey You're welcome, glad I could help. If you feel satisfied, I would appreciate an upvote/acceptance of my answer.